# Why I can not use a variable for the :eq filter to append data to an unordered list?

Tags: jquery

Why I can not use a variable counter for the :eq filter to append data to an unordered list?

For example, the code is not working. It not being updated into the div of unordered list.

```
 $('#list li:eq("+ counter +")').append('<li>' + variable + '<li>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the string issue that Shadow Wizard mentions, if you're trying to add another `li` tag on the same level as `#list li`, then you're code isn't right.  Append, will add a child so:

```
$('#list li').eq(n).append('<li>' + variable + '</li>')
```

adds an `LI` tag inside the nth `LI` tag, not after the nth `LI` tag.  From the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> *The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child
>   of each element in the jQuery collection*

You may be interested in the [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method if what you're trying to do is to insert a new `LI` tag after an existing `LI` tag, but at the same level:

```
$('#list li').eq(n).after('<li>' + variable + '</li>')
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PHkm4/ for a working example.

Comment: Good catch, this never occurred to me!

Comment: thanks jfriend00 but still not working after using your suggestion, $('#ul_b li').eq(b_counter).insertAfter('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>'); .. I think the problem is li are never created. In other words, I use an each loop to append the data into this unordered list for the first time. When using no eq counter, it works but I was wondering if I could use eq filter counter to append the data but that is not working nor is your suggestion

Comment: Ahhh, jQuery confusion.  It's actually the `.after()` method you want.  I've updated my answer and added a working jsFiddle to make sure we got it right.

Comment: FYI, your code also had a typo when `<li>' + variable + '<li>` should have been this: `<li>' + variable + '</li>`.

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax:

```
$('#list li:eq(' + counter +')')
```

You must use the same string delimeters, can't mix them in same string.

More elegant syntax would be:

```
$('#list li').eq(counter)
```

This way no need to mess with string delimeters at all.

Comment: it does not work,  $('#ul_b li').eq(b_counter).append('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>');

Comment: this does not work either,  $('#ul_b li').eq(0).append('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>');

Comment: but this works,  $('#ul_b').append('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>');

Comment: Yep see jfriend00 answer as well - I was just correcting your syntax problems.