# The eq fliter is not working

Tags: jquery

Why this code is not working? Meaning nothing get displayed into the ul tag.

```
$("#server").each(function()
{
  var textValue = $(this).text();

  $('#list li').eq(counter).append('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>');      // <-- not working
  $('#list li').eq(counter).insertAfter('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>'); // <-- or not working
  $('#list')append('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>');                      // <-- or working
});

<div>
     <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: did you mean `.each(function(counter) {...});` Also, #server is an id and should occur only once. If you meant for it to be a class `.server` should be used as the selector.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `#server` can only match a single element.
2. `counter` is undefined.
3. `#list` does not contain any items, so `#list li` will not match anything.
4. You are missing a period before `append`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.

1. `$('#list li')` doesn't resolve to anything since there is no `<li>` yet. It should be `ul` instead.
2. If you're looking at a specific index with `eq` during iteration, you may want to pass in the current index into the functor, like so: `$('#server').each(function(counter){...` - but maybe `counter` comes from somewhere else, that's not clear from your posting.

Regards
db

Answer (score 0):

I think your full answer is [here in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640555/why-i-can-not-use-a-variable-for-the-eq-filter-to-append-data-to-an-unordered-li/7640717#7640717) on this topic (read the comments to your questions in my answer).

I think you want jQuery's method `.after()` instead of `.insertAfter()`.  Full working example including a jsFiddle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640555/why-i-can-not-use-a-variable-for-the-eq-filter-to-append-data-to-an-unordered-li/7640717#7640717).

```
$('#list li').eq(counter).after('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>');
```